# Rails 5 + Bootstrap 4 buttons alignment/position issue

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, bootstrap-4

Code https://github.com/tenzan/shop/tree/bootstrap

As in the image below (`show` action), buttons Edit and Delete are positioned vertically.
I'ld like to change position as per 2nd image below, i.e. both buttons to be aligned with a **Test** word.

`show.html.erb`:

```
<header>
  <h1><%= @category.name %></h1>

  <ul class="actions">
    <li><%= link_to "Edit Category", edit_category_path(@category),
            class: "edit"  %></li>

    <li><%= link_to "Delete Category", category_path(@category),
       method: :delete,
       data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this category?" },
        class: "delete" %></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Those 2 buttons stylesheet looks like (See `a.edit` and `a.delete` part):

```
ul.actions {
  @extend .list-unstyled;
  @extend .list-inline;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: 2px;
  max-width: 45%;
  text-align: right;
}
a.new, a.edit, a.delete {
  @extend .btn;
  &:before {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    padding-right: 0.5em;
  }
}
a.new {
  @extend .btn-success;
  &:before {
    @extend .fa-plus;
  }
}
a.edit {
  @extend .btn-primary;
  &:before {
    @extend .fa-pencil;
  }
}
a.delete {
  @extend .btn-danger;
  &:before {
    @extend .fa-trash;
  }
}
```

**This is how it looks now**
[image]

**This is how I want it to be**
[image]

Comment: Any reason in particular to have `<li>`?? can be changed??

Comment: Actually, removing `<li>`s fixed the issue... But I was following _Rails 4 in Action_ book where they used `<li>`s but with bootstrap 3. Can you please post your comment as an Answer so I can accept it? Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Let me add another solution, that might be helpfull for you.

Comment: Cool! That'd be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. The Simple Way:

To show the "Edit Category" and "Delete Category" in one single line just need to remove the `<li>` tags. That wolud be something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <%= link_to "Edit Category", edit_category_path(@category),
            class: "edit"  %> 
  ...
</ul>
```

---

#### 2. Apply CSS:

Let's asume that you can't change the `<li>` tags, you can apply this style with CSS:

```
ul { list-style: none; }    /* Remove list bullets */
ul li { display: inline; }  /* Display <li> elements as inline elements */
```